# Making a Custom Operator Window Continue to be on top, blender python

Tags: python, operator

With the below code I am able to create window. But when I click on viewport the windows doesn’t stay on top and it goes off. I want to stay the window unless I close by clicking on OK button.

```
class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_operator"
    bl_label = "My Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Do some action here
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

     def draw(self, context):
         layout = self.layout
         col = layout.column()
         col.label(text="Select an action:")
         col.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
         col.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # Test the operator
    bpy.ops.object.my_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added additional details on what exactly the requirement is.